# Neither migrations nor loading schema adds a column to Rails/MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-migrations

I've created a migration to add an `is_ms_admin` column to my MySQL database in Rails:

```
class AddIsAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :is_ms_admin, :boolean
  end
end
```

This has correspondingly updated the schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "", null: false
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,   default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.boolean  "is_approved"
  t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.boolean  "is_ms_admin"
end
```

On running `rake db:migrate`, the migration runs without throwing any errors. Using `rake db:schema:load` is also error-free. Both appear to be successful.

When I select the column names from the MySQL table, however, only *most* of the columns exist:

```
mysql> SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
    -> FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    -> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='metasmoke' 
    ->     AND `TABLE_NAME`='users';
+---------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME         |
+---------------------+
| id                  |
| email               |
| encrypted_password  |
| remember_created_at |
| sign_in_count       |
| current_sign_in_at  |
| last_sign_in_at     |
| current_sign_in_ip  |
| last_sign_in_ip     |
| created_at          |
| updated_at          |
| is_approved         |
+---------------------+
```

I'm primarily concerned with the `is_ms_admin` column, but it would also be useful to know why the two `reset_password` columns don't exist.

I'm not running all this from the Rails console, so the issue is not because the console has cached things; having reloaded the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table too, it's apparent that *the columns aren't created at all*, rather than being any surrounding issue.

Why does the column not exist, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There may well be more information required, but I don't know what - yell if you want to see something.

Comment: you probly have already, but just in case, reload the rails console with the reload! command.

Comment: by reading this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html, I this comment: TABLE_ROWS (and perhaps some other columns in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES) may get out of sync with the current table contents, but you can update it by running ANALYZE. So, it might be something like that.

Comment: @fanta 'fraid not, I've still got the same columns. I think it actually isn't getting created, rather than being a surrounding issue.

Comment: @volx757 I'm not actually in the rails console, just a mysql shell. Restarting that hasn't done anything.

Comment: Aren't you looking at the test database instead ? :D

Comment: @fanta shouldn't be, no - database.yml specifies the dev database as `metasmoke`