# Rails migration adds column to schema but not postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I am adding a column to an existing table in my DB. The migration created here:

```
// ♥ rails g migration AddFieldToRecipes
Running via Spring preloader in process 80952
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20180628220935_add_field_to_recipes.rb
```

Edited here:

```
class AddFieldToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
   add_column :recipes, :cooked, :boolean, null: false, default: false
  end
end
```

Is run here:

```
// ♥ rails db:migrate
== 20180628220935 AddFieldToRecipes: migrating 
================================
-- add_column(:recipes, :cooked, :boolean, {:null=>false, 
:default=>false})
-> 0.0079s
== 20180628220935 AddFieldToRecipes: migrated (0.0080s) 
=======================
```

Does change the schema:

```
  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "cooked", default: false, null: false
  end
```

And the ActiveRecord sees the change when I run:
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns("recipes")`

```
=> [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x00007f8b69f91018
  @collation=nil,
  @comment=nil,
  @default=nil,
  @default_function="nextval('recipes_id_seq'::regclass)",
  @max_identifier_length=63,
  @name="id",
  @null=false,
  @sql_type_metadata=
   #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x00007f8b69f912c0 @limit=8, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @sql_type="bigint", @type=:integer>,
  @table_name="recipes">,
 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x00007f8b69f905c8
  @collation=nil,
  @comment=nil,
  @default=nil,
  @default_function=nil,
  @max_identifier_length=63,
  @name="created_at",
  @null=false,
  @sql_type_metadata=
   #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x00007f8b69f90960
    @limit=nil,
    @precision=nil,
    @scale=nil,
    @sql_type="timestamp without time zone",
    @type=:datetime>,
  @table_name="recipes">,
 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x00007f8b6ad6f860
  @collation=nil,
  @comment=nil,
  @default=nil,
  @default_function=nil,
  @max_identifier_length=63,
  @name="updated_at",
  @null=false,
  @sql_type_metadata=
   #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x00007f8b6ad6fc48
    @limit=nil,
    @precision=nil,
    @scale=nil,
    @sql_type="timestamp without time zone",
    @type=:datetime>,
  @table_name="recipes">,
 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x00007f8b6ad6edc0
  @collation=nil,
  @comment=nil,
  @default="false",
  @default_function=nil,
  @max_identifier_length=63,
  @name="cooked",
  @null=false,
  @sql_type_metadata=
   #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x00007f8b6ad6ef78 @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @sql_type="boolean", @type=:boolean>,
  @table_name="recipes">]
```

But is not reflected on the model when in the console (or in the app):

```
[1] pry(main)> Recipe.columns.map { |c| c.name }
=> ["id", "title", "description", "author", "user_id", "type", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

So I tried resetting the column information:

```
[2] pry(main)> Recipe.reset_column_information
=> {true=>#<Concurrent::Map:0x007f8b69681cc0 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, false=>#<Concurrent::Map:0x007f8b69681c20 entries=0 default_proc=nil>}
```

Still no change:

```
[3] pry(main)> Recipe.columns.map { |c| c.name }
=> ["id", "title", "description", "author", "user_id", "type", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

Based on many (many) questions/answers found here (also another of [the same exact question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093961/neither-migrations-nor-loading-schema-adds-a-column-to-rails-mysql-database)), I have rolled back the migration and reran it -- same. Rolled back, and reloaded the schema, reran -- same. Since it's dev, I also dropped the DB, created, migrated -- same.

**What am I missing?** I just want to be able to have `recipe.cooked` show me true or false.

Comment: add the column through `psql` directly and verify it's reflecting or not.

Comment: That looks really frustrating. I just tried running your same migration on a clean Rails 5.2 + PostgreSQL 10.4 app using the `pg` 1.0 gem and didn't have that problem. I had to contrive my own Recipe and original migration though. Is your project code published somewhere?

Comment: Did you restart application after migration? Can you change migration to raw sql query and test it?

Comment: @Gokulp I checked in psql and the column is reflected `ink_dev=# select * from "recipes" where false;
 id | created_at | updated_at | cooked 
----+------------+------------+--------
(0 rows)`

Comment: @ArtemDorodovskyi I did restart my application. Maybe it's not a sql issue if the column shows up in `psql`? I will rollback and try when back at my desk.

Comment: @JonM. code is [here](https://github.com/psswf1172/in_the_kitchen).  Rails 5.2/pg 1.0/postgresql app on my computer is 9.5.

Comment: @psswf Maybe the repository is private or hasn't been pushed yet; I'm getting a 404 there.

Comment: Try quit the console, run `spring stop && rails console` and recheck columns

Comment: @psswf better try with `pg gem with version 0.21.0`

Comment: There is too much issues with `pg 1.0`

Comment: @JonM. Sorry about that! I forgot it was private -- I just made it public.

Comment: @Vasilisa I stopped spring, opened the rails console and still no cooked column.

Comment: @Gokulp I switched to pg 0.21.0, dropped/created/migrated, restarted app -- same.

Comment: @psswf still you facing the problem??

Comment: @Gokulp yes :(  Even more concerning, I generated a new migration for a different column on another model and the same thing has happened. It's like ActiveRecord isn't sending the changes to Rails.